# How to select average data greter than some value in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

[image]

How can I select average salaries of those departments where the average salary is greter than `65000`?

I tried this query, but it does not work:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         `instructer`.`dept_name`, 
         AVG(`instructer`.`salary`) AS Average
     FROM 
         `instructer`
     GROUP BY 
         `instructer`.`dept_name)
WHERE 
    `Average` > 65000
```

`Solved Query:`

```
SELECT 
      `instructer`.`dept_name`, AVG(`instructer`.`salary`) AS AVGSalary
FROM 
      `instructer`
GROUP BY 
      `instructer`.`dept_name`
HAVING 
      (`AVGSalary`) > 65000
```

Comment: `HAVING AVG(`instructer`.`salary`) > 65000`

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (MySQL?)

Comment: Your column seems to have the name "name" and not "instructer" (instructor).

Comment: How did your query not work?  If you are using MySQL, you are just missing a table alias after the subquery.

Answer (score 2):

Hey Try this query hope it helps you

```
select DEPARTMENT, avg(SALARY) as AVGSalary
 from instructer
 group by DEPARTMENT
having avg(SALARY) >65000
```

Comment: this should be used, because it does only ONE query, no subquery needed

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
SELECT `instructer`.`dept_name`, AVG(`instructer`.`salary`)
               AS Average
              FROM `instructer`
              GROUP BY `instructer`.`dept_name HAVING AVG(`instructer`.`salary`) > 65000
```

I hope this will helpful to you